# System Error: Invalid object name 'Database name '

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, ssms

I am trying to run a program to where the function is to export a report to excel file. So far, it works on other type of report when I click generate, but on this particular report,Game Transaction Report, I get the error : "System error: invalid object name 'GCVS2.dbo.GameTrx".  This is the code for this case:

```
db.Open();
command = new SqlCommand("M_RPT_GameTransactionReport", db);
strControlValue = GetControlValue(pnlRecordRange, "useDateTimeFrom", ControlType.LabelDateTimePickerFrom);
if (strControlValue != null)
{
    // dtFrom = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Parse(strControlValue).ToShortDateString());
    dtFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(strControlValue);

}

strControlValue1 = GetControlValue(pnlRecordRange, "useDateTimeTo", ControlType.LabelDateTimePickerTo);
if (strControlValue1 != null)
{
    dtTo = Convert.ToDateTime(strControlValue1);
    // if (dtTo != DateTime.MinValue)
    //     dtTo = MaxTimeOfDate(dtTo);
}

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventCode",strEvCode );
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PromotionBenefitCode",strPromotionBenefitCode );
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DtFrom",dtFrom );
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DtTo",dtTo );
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardIdFrom",strCardIDFrom );
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardIDTo",strCardIDTo );
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNo",strSerialNo );
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status",strStatus );




command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandTimeout = 0;
dr = command.ExecuteReader();
ExportExcel(dr);
db.Close();
```

How do i fix this?

Edit: Below is the sql script for the stored procedure for GameTransactionReport:

```
   ` CREATE       PROCEDURE [M_RPT_GameTransactionReport]
    @EventCode varchar(8),
    @PromotionBenefitCode varchar (100),
    @CardIDFrom varchar(50),
    @CardIDTo varchar(50),
    @SerialNo varchar(15),
    @DtFrom datetime,
    @DtTo datetime,
    @Status CHAR(1)
    AS`

    SET NOCOUNT ON`

`SELECT G.[GameTrxID]
      ,G.[EventCode]
      ,PE.[Description]
      ,G.[PromotionBenefitCode]
      ,G.[GameSetupID]
      ,GE.[GameSetupDescription]
      ,G.[GameInventoryID]
      ,G.[GameUnlimitedInventoryID]
      ,G.[CardId]
      ,G.[VisiblePoint]
      ,G.[HiddenPoint]
      ,G.[LoyaltyPoint]
      ,G.[VisiblePointEarn]
      ,G.[TradingDate]
      ,G.[VoucherSerialNo]
      ,G.[Winner]
      ,G.[TerminalID]
      ,T.[ComputerName]
      ,G.[CreateBy]
      ,G.[CreateDate]
      ,G.[Status]
      ,G.[CancelReason]
      ,G.[LastChangeBy]
      ,G.[LastChangeDate]`
      `


`FROM [GCVS2].[dbo].[GameTrx] G,PromotionEvent PE, GameEventSetup GE ,
    Terminal T with (nolock)`

`WHERE
G.TerminalID =T.TerminalID
AND
G.EventCode = PE.EventCode
AND
G.GameSetupID = GE.GameSetupID
AND 
(@DtFrom IS NULL OR 
G.[TradingDate] >= @DtFrom )
AND 
(@DtTo IS NULL OR 
G.[TradingDate] <= @DtTo)
AND
(@EventCode = '' OR (G.EventCode = @EventCode))
AND
(@PromotionBenefitCode = '' OR (G.PromotionBenefitCode = @PromotionBenefitCode))
AND
(@CardIDFrom = '' OR (G.CardID >= @CardIDFrom))
AND
(@CardIDTo = '' OR (G.CardID <= @CardIDTo))
AND
(@SerialNo = '' OR (G.VoucherSerialNo = @SerialNo))
AND 
(@Status = '' OR (G.Status = @Status))`
```

Comment: This isn't a C# error. it's an SQL error coming from a mistake / problem in the stored procedure. As a side note, you should wrap things like SqlCommand in a `using(  ...  ) {  ...  }` statement

Comment: So the error is in SSMS? Do I need to change the name to something else?

Comment: Somehow, dbo.gametrx exists in my database. so not sure why i still get the error.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your stored procedure and relevant database schema.

Comment: Check if you are connecting to the right database, in case the database is right? can you paste the stored procedure code to clarify issue

Comment: Coding, already edited the post, see my stored procedure, I believe the mistake is from "`FROM [GCVS2].[dbo].[GameTrx] G,PromotionEvent PE, GameEventSetup GE ....." as the error claimed it doesn't have the object name or maybe i have to rename it?

Comment: Yes i am connected to the right database, because other report functions in other cases are able to export report to excel, but not this one.

Comment: Is the table in the same database?

Comment: yup is it in the database

Comment: I suspect it's the naming convention. When I look and tried to modify  the stored procedure, it says like G.TerminalID could not be bound with red line, same goes to those parameters with G on it.

Comment: Remove `[GCVS2]` and try again

Comment: Maybe i have to name it FROM GameTrx, instead of GCVS2.[dbo]? I looked into the other stored procedure where it's working and it doesn't seem to have [dbo] naming.

Comment: I have to modify the stored procedure first right

Comment: Okay it works now!!!! Can you post your answer and ill mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the stored procedure and change this line:

```
FROM [GCVS2].[dbo].[GameTrx]
```

to

```
 FROM [dbo].[GameTrx]
```